# Downloading a Dynamic CSV in Internet Explorer 11 & Safari 5.1.7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, csv, safari, dojo

I know there are lot of answer for this question given by experts, but i didn't found any answer for Safari.
In safari when try to download ".CSV" file, it opens in new window with download folder but nothing is happening, it is not downloading or showing me the CSV file.

Here is my code for .csv download.
csvdata is string not json file

```
_exportToCSV: function (csvdata, fileName) {           
            var link, oWin, click_ev;
            if (this.IsIE) {
                oWin = window.top.open("about:blank", "_blank");
                oWin.document.open("application/csv", "replace");
                oWin.document.charset = "utf-8";
                oWin.document.write(csvdata.csvdata);
                oWin.document.close();
                oWin.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName);
                oWin.close();
            } else {
                link = domConstruct.create("a", {
                    href: 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csvdata.csvdata),
                    target: '_blank',
                    download: fileName + ".csv"
                }, this.domNode);
                if (this.IsSafari) {
                    click_ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                    click_ev.initEvent("click", true, true);
                    link.dispatchEvent(click_ev);
                } else {
                    link.click();
                }
                domConstruct.destroy(link);
            }
        }
```